# post_max_size in php5-cgi.ini -> Do i have to restart my Server?

Tags: php

i want to change the size of the post_max_size limit.
I tried it with a new php5-cgi.ini in the directory.
In the php5-cgi.ini i've set the limit to 32M.

`phpinfo();` says my limit is now 32M bit when i call
    `echo ini_get('post_max_size');`
it echoes "8M" and uploads doesn't work.

Do i have to restart my server now, or what can be the issue?

Best regards

Comment: You do not have to restart the server, just restart Apache (web service) / PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will have to restart apache for this to take affect.